# Appliying default styles through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

After the page is loaded, if we are doing some changes in the look of the page like style using JavaScript or jQuery, is it possible to revert it back to the default state (i.e., To the state when the page loaded) without reloading the page? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a blank style on an element with `.css()` will reset that style. From the [jQuery documentation for `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property.

For example:

```
$('div#green').css('background', 'red').css('background', '');
```

Will reset `div#green` to have a green background again *assuming it did in the first place*.

There is one (albeit sensible) caveat to take into account, however. The `.css()` documentation states that:

> It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or `<style>` element.

Answer (score 1):

To revert the entire page, assuming that you are not using inline styles for your defaults (which you shouldn't be), you can use:

```
$('*[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```
$(function() {
      var original = $('body').clone();
});

function revert_to_original() {
    $('body').html(original);
}
```

But with this one you will probably have to rebind all of your events, and you have to make sure you grab the original before any changes get made to the DOM.

Otherwise, you can remove the specific style you want to reset with

```
$('#element').css('whatever style', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to track which styles are applied and undo the changes. Best way to do that would probably be to create a `setStyle` function, like this:

```
var stylesChanged = [];
function setStyle(element, style, value) {
    element.style[style] = value;

    stylesChanged.push({
        element: element,
        style: style,
        previousValue: element.style
    });

    return element;
}
```

And then you could have a `resetStyles` function, like so:

```
function resetStyles() {
    for(style in stylesChanged) {
        stylesChanged[style].element.style = stylesChanged[style].previousValue;
    }
}
```

So instead of manually changing the styles on an element, you'd set the style with the setStyle function, like this:

```
setStyle(document.getElementById("someElement"), "color", "white");
```

It's a little more work but the upside of this technique is you won't lose any of your previously bound events or anything.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this would be to use classes. Add your class styles to the page, then use addClass() and removeClass() to switch between custom and default styles.